# Maps sdk which support all countries

Tags: ios, swift

### Maps sdk which supports all countries

i am developing an app that supports all countries. I used maps in app but i read those documents which says that google maps not supports in china. What can i do for this i searched for many but am not getting exact result. which map supports in all countries.

```
let mapview = GMSMapview()
if Locale.current.regionCode == "IN" {
mapview.isHidden = false
} else {
//which map can i use
}
```

Comment: use apple core map which is supporting china

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use [OMS](https://www.openstreetmap.org/), it supports a lot of countries and you can contribute by yourself.
Libraries for iOS https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Apple_iOS#Libraries_for_developers